# what ia local minimum when there is a jump or in end of interval?

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am wondering is (2,2) local minimum or (2,3)? how about end of intervals?

Comment: The value of the function $g(x)$ at $x=2$ is $2$ not $3$.

Comment: Here it appears that $(2,2)$ is a local minimum, $(3,1)$ is the global minimum, $(4,2)$ is a local minimum, and the function isn't defined at $0$ so there is no global maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a point is a local minimum point at $x^∗$ if $f(x^∗) ≤ f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ within distance $ε$ of $x$. Here, $ε$ is arbitrarily small.

Following this definition, we have that $(2,2)$ is a local minimum.